# How can I restore the initial centralwidget of the QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

I am kinda of new to Qt and decided to play around with it a bit so that one day I may be able to make some programs with a GUI. I've been playing around with windows and encountered a problem. I created two new QWidget Form classes in addition to the QMainWindow. With one of them, I was able to make a separate window popup and disappear. What I am trying to do with the second one is this...

I have a MainWindow with a button, and when that button is pressed, the CentralWidget changes to the QWidget with another button. Then, when I press a button on the new button, it restores the CentralWidget to the original one.

I did try storing the initial CentralWidget before changing it but I have yet to be able to successfully restore it. I do know about QStackedWidget, but I would like to know if there is another way of doing it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

It seems Qt deletes child widget, when new one assigned as child widget. The fallowing code illustrates it and shows workaround

```
class QMyWidget: public QWidget
{
public:
    ~QMyWidget(){std::cout<<"Destroyed"<<std::endl;}
};

class QMyWidget2: public QWidget
{
public:
    ~QMyWidget2(){std::cout<<"Destroyed2"<<std::endl;}
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(new QMyWidget());
    this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget);

    QWidget * w = new QMyWidget2();
    this->setCentralWidget(w);
    w->setParent(NULL);
    this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that matters, but all my widgets were designed using the designer, so they all have a separate Ui and setupUi

Answer (score 0):

Do you want [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html)? It's a but like QTabWidget but without the, er, tabs.